# HTML - onmouseover, onmouseout - Element click error- Object variable or with block not set Error 91

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

I have a website where I got Menu bar which is in frame 1 and its sub menus are in frame 2. Now I have found all the element where I need to go. But problem that I am facing is that if I manually hover on those menu then code works but if I don't I get error no 91. Can you please help me resolve this issue? below is the code that I am using for the same.

Once I hover on 1st option its html changes, when I hover over 2nd menu option again HTML code changes. How do I control it?

IMPORT (hover) -> STATIC DATA (hover) -> ISIN (CLICK)

```
Sub test()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim doc, element
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
Dim frm
Dim menu
Dim submenu
Dim submenu2

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

    IE.Document.all("usr_name").Value = uName
    IE.Document.all("password").Value = pwd
    IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")(7).Click

    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Sleep (2000)
Set doc = IE.Document
Sleep (5000)

'doc.frames(0).Document.getElementsByTagName("Body")(0).getElementsByTagName("Div")(5).FireEvent ("onclick")
'
'Sleep (2000)
'doc.frames(1).Document.getElementsByTagName("Body")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).FireEvent ("onclick")

For Each element In doc.frames(0).Document.getElementsByTagName("Body")(0).getElementsByTagName("Div")
    Debug.Print element.innerHTML
    If InStr(1, element.innerHTML, "IMPORT", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
         element.Click
         Exit For
    End If
Next

'Frame 2 sub menu...I think I need something which can hover over these menu
For Each element In doc.frames(1).Document.getElementsByTagName("Body")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")

    Debug.Print element.innerHTML
    If InStr(1, element.innerHTML, "Static Data", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
         element.Click
         Exit For
    End If

Next

'This is where I click
For Each element In doc.frames(1).Document.getElementsByTagName("Body")(0).getElementsByTagName("div")

    If InStr(1, element.innerHTML, "ISIN", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print element.innerHTML
        element.Click
        Exit For
    End If
    Debug.Print element.innerHTML

Next element

'doc.frames(1).Document.getElementsByTagName("Body")(0).getElementsByTagName("Span")(28).Click  '' ISIN

End Sub
```

Please let me know if I need to provide any other data here. Please find below the html when I have not hover over the menu...

```html
<TR>
<TD onclick=fSetSelected(this) onmouseover=this.bgColor=gcToggle onmouseout=this.bgColor=gcBG id=calCell style="CURSOR: hand; FONT: bold 16px Courier" bgColor=#cccccc height=18 vAlign=middle borderColor=#cccccc align=center><FONT id=cellText Victor="Liming Weng"></FONT></TD>
<TD onclick=fSetSelected(this) onmouseover=this.bgColor=gcToggle onmouseout=this.bgColor=gcBG id=calCell style="CURSOR: hand; FONT: bold 16px Courier" bgColor=#cccccc height=18 vAlign=middle borderColor=#cccccc align=center><FONT id=cellText Victor="Liming Weng"></FONT></TD>
<TD onclick=fSetSelected(this) onmouseover=this.bgColor=gcToggle onmouseout=this.bgColor=gcBG id=calCell style="CURSOR: hand; FONT: bold 16px Courier" bgColor=#cccccc height=18 vAlign=middle borderColor=#cccccc align=center><FONT id=cellText Victor="Liming Weng"></FONT></TD>
<TD onclick=fSetSelected(this) onmouseover=this.bgColor=gcToggle onmouseout=this.bgColor=gcBG id=calCell style="CURSOR: hand; FONT: bold 16px Courier" bgColor=#cccccc height=18 vAlign=middle borderColor=#cccccc align=center><FONT id=cellText Victor="Liming Weng"></FONT></TD>
<TD onclick=fSetSelected(this) onmouseover=this.bgColor=gcToggle onmouseout=this.bgColor=gcBG id=calCell style="CURSOR: hand; FONT: bold 16px Courier" bgColor=#cccccc height=18 vAlign=middle borderColor=#cccccc align=center><FONT id=cellText Victor="Liming Weng"></FONT></TD>
<TD onclick=fSetSelected(this) onmouseover=this.bgColor=gcToggle onmouseout=this.bgColor=gcBG id=calCell style="CURSOR: hand; FONT: bold 16px Courier" bgColor=#cccccc height=18 vAlign=middle borderColor=#cccccc align=center><FONT id=cellText Victor="Liming Weng"></FONT></TD>
<TD onclick=fSetSelected(this) onmouseover=this.bgColor=gcToggle onmouseout=this.bgColor=gcBG id=calCell style="CURSOR: hand; FONT: bold 16px Courier" bgColor=#cccccc height=18 vAlign=middle borderColor=#cccccc align=center><FONT id=cellText Victor="Liming Weng"></FONT></TD></TR>
<TR>

<TD onclick=fSetSelected(this) onmouseo
SETUP

ver=this.bgColoIMPORT

EXPORT

REPORTS

BILLING

MIS

DOC TRACKING

LOG OUT &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
r=gcToggle onmouseout=this.bgColor=gcBG id=calCell style="CURSOR: hand; FONT: bold 16px Courier" bgColor=#cccccc height=18 vAlign=middle borderColor=#cccccc align=center><FONT id=cellText Victor="Liming Weng"></FONT></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
```

Below code I found in javascript: Woruld it be any help understanding the issue?

```js
oCFMenu.makeTop('IMPORT') //Main 2
    oCFMenu.makeSub('Static Data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&raquo;')
        oCFMenu.makeSub2('ISIN','import_isin.asp','frmMain')
        oCFMenu.makeSub2('Business Partner','import_bp.asp','frmMain')
        oCFMenu.makeSub2('CC Calender','import_cccalender.asp','frmMain')
        oCFMenu.makeSub2('Auto Corporate','import_autocorporate.asp','frmMain')
        oCFMenu.makeSub2('CA (Corporate Action)','import_autocorporateCA.asp','frmMain')
```

Below are the relevent html for IMPORT, STATIC DATA and ISIN

```html
<DIV id=divTop1 class=clMain style="CLIP: rect(0px 126px 20px 0px); HEIGHT: 20px; WIDTH: 126px; LEFT: 80px; TOP: 39px; VISIBILITY: visible; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cccccc">IMPORT</DIV>

<DIV id=divSub0 class=clSubs style="LEFT: 80px; TOP: 0px; VISIBILITY: visible; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cccccc"><SPAN class=clSub style="COLOR: white">Static Data&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;»</SPAN></DIV>

<DIV id=divSub2_0 class=clSubs2 style="LEFT: 239px; TOP: 8px; VISIBILITY: visible; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #cccccc"><SPAN class=clSub2 style="COLOR: white">ISIN</SPAN></DIV>
```

Comment: I have removed the JavaScript tag.

Comment: Is it a form as opposed to a button (have you tried `.Submit`)?

Comment: 1st two loop are useless. If I manually hover over the menu it kind of generate its elements, then 3rd loop works fine. Only problem I am having is that I dont know how write code to hover over the menu so that it generates relevant code. And for your question there are no submit option except at the beginning wnem I logging into the website.

Comment: Please share your html.

Comment: I have shared HTML when I have not hovered over the menu. I have no idea how to work this. I want to hover over 'IMPORT' first then 'STATIC DATA' then click on 'ISIN'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Since it was issue of simple mouseover which I believe didnot interpret the way others understood, I figured it out by myself. Instead of using click event I made only one change and it works like a charm.

```
element.FireEvent "onmouseover"
```